# Sql Server 2005/08 problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My query is giving different search results for Sql Server 05 and 08

In Sql Server 2005, search results are working fine.

```
 select * from Table_name where column_name like '%summer%' and column_name like '%vacation%'  
 --Giving 9 results  
 select * from Table_name where column_name like '%summer-vacation%' 
 --Giving 9 same results
```

In Sql Server 2008, search results are

```
 select * from Table_name where column_name like '%summer%' and column_name like '%vacation%'  
 --Giving 7 results    
 select * from Table_name where column_name like '%summer-vacation%' 
 --Giving the other 2 results
```

Comment: Your queries are different; why would you expect them to return the same results? Are you certain that the data in the tables is actually the same?

Comment: Even after your edit the top queries in each pair are still quite clearly and obviously different.

Comment: Is the collation the same? Possibly a difference in case sensitivity? Try comparing the casing of the results returned (or not returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All things being equal between the two databases, I'd expect the second summer/vacation to return at least as many rows as the first summer/vacation.

However, the second query isn't equivalent.

Can you post the actual results?

Also, do your databases have the same collation?

Comment: Did you mean spaces in the `LIKE` argument? I don't see any spaces in the column names.

Comment: @Adam Robinson Sorry, I saw column_name and thought he was querying the metadata (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES).  I see that Table_name is just a dummy table name.

Comment: Yes..both the tables are same & table_name, column_name are dummy names

Comment: @user: The fact that you've revised the query multiple times makes me think that something is missing in your translation. Why not post the *actual* queries that are returning different results?

Comment: Sorry from my side guys..I have changed the 2nd query one last time and this time I am as careful as ever..sorry once again

Comment: @user: Please post the actual queries that are not working correctly, not queries that you believe represent them.

Answer (score 0):

And why do you assume both databases actually have the same number of records that meet the criteria? (BTW searching that way is an indication of bad design as you cannot use indexes when you have a wildcard as the first character.)

Comment: I wonder why people say things like "bad design" when they've seen a description of some problem not necessarily related to design at all? Your point is that in a different design a search can be performed more efficiently. OP does not ask that. What they want to know is why they queries return different results. In addition it never hurts the poster when someone when they say something is bad, provide and example of how it can be improved.

Comment: @zespri,we say bad design to make the person think about their design. It is a known fact that wildcards in the first position of a like statement means you cannot use the indexes in the query. That means it's a bad design. The other issue is irrelevant if they fix the design. I don't always have time to redesign someone's system, but I can point out that they need to. It would be unprofessional to let something like this pass without comment, it's that bad.

Comment: Just to get this straight, 1) it's your professional opinion, that people should be banned from issuing queries that can't use indexes? 2) You have a system, that does not use wildcard in the first position to search. You (as a developer) need to run one-time query purely out of curiosity about the underlying data that DOES use wildcard in the first position to search. This query runs relatively fast because there is not a lot of data in the table. Will you redesign the whole system to run one-time query that exposes no problems in itself?